# Azure Function can watchFiles used for caching?

Tags: c#, azure, caching, azure-functions

I have a use case where my function is triggered by a queue. To be able to process the message, it needs some configuration, which I can get via an API.

This configuration changes a couple of times a day, but is relatively static. I can receive an event / message when the configuration changes.

To limit the number of requests to the API and not being fully dependent on the API being up, I would like to cache this configuration.

Since functions are short lived, memory caching didn't seem to be the right option. And each instance of my function should have a copy of the configuration.

Of course, I could consider a Redis cache, but I was hoping to find a more cost efficient solution.

I came across the `watchFiles` property which can be set in the host.json of an Azure Function. [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#watchfiles). What I like about this, is that any changes to these files are picked up by the instances of the function. I was thinking of writing a configuration to a json file which I configure in watchFiles. Each time I receive an event of a configuration change, I can update the content of the file. The change of the file would then be picked up by the other instances of the function as well.

Unfortunately I couldn't find much documentation about this feature.

Would this work for the cache requirements I have? In case someone has some example code, that would be much appreciated.

Btw, I am using C# .NET 6.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I got it to work locally.

Add to the `host.json` the following:
`"watchFiles": [ "localCache.json" ]`

Somewhere in code, write data to the file. This can simply be done with for example:

```cs
var content = "Some content I want to cache.";
File.WriteAllText("localCache.json", content);
```

Reading works in a similar way:

```cs
var content = File.ReadAllText("localCache.json");
```

In my case I serialized the data to JSON first and stored that to the file.

Each time data was written to the file, the function app instance was restarted.

There was one big showstopper for me: this doesn't work if you are using Zip-deploy. Then the filesystem is read-only and you can't write to the file.

Since I wanted to keep using zip-deploy, I am now considering writing a cache to a storage account I am already interacting with anyway.